# How to fix auth error in Blazor WASM .NET 7 upgrade?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Ever since I updated my blazor wasm project which is hosted as a static site on azure to .Net 7, users have been getting redirected to "______.com/authentication/login-failed" even though the authentication is working properly.  They can then navigate around the site with out issue, but not without seeing this error.

I can't reproduce this problem locally (only happens in azure production environment), and the only error I get is a 404 not found.

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The requested content does not exist.)"

Has anyone else experienced this, and hopefully found a solution?

I could roll back to .Net 6, but that had a ton of other authentication related problems, which .Net7 had fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the client.csproj should fix it:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" />
</ItemGroup>
```

source https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44981